# Cisco ip phone - leaving prerecorded voicemails for outbound sales campaign

Tags: sales

I made 1000 outbound calls through a cisco ip phone last week, and a lot of them were just me leaving someone a voice mail. I was hoping some one knew of a hack to cut my number of voice mails in half by essentially leaving a prerecorded message instead of having to speak through the receiver every time.

Thank you.

Comment: Please see http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2431/a-lifehacks-manifesto — "Questions about using products in the way they were designed to be used (e.g. keyboard shortcuts, obscure features, how to get your smartphone to do {x}) are outside the scope of this site."